# NPM installs older version & doesn't fully installs recursive dependencies

Tags: json, node.js, dependencies, npm, lodash

In a project I inherited, the packages.json looks roughly like this:

```
{
  "name": "...",
  "version": "...",
  "description": "",
  "author": "...",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^3.10.1",
    "assemble": "^0.4.37",
    "cheerio": "^0.16.0",
    "grunt": "^0.4.4",
    "grunt-build-control": "^0.1.3",

  },
  "keywords": [
    "handlebars-helper-md",
    "handlebars-helper-rel"
  ]
}
```

When I first got it, `lodash` was `~2.4.1` and I'm trying to update it to `3.10.1` (as shown above). However, `npm` continues to install `2.4.1` at the top-level (Despite the `package.json` requesting the newer version) and it does not install the requested versions `2.4.1` or `2.4.2` in some of the dependencies (like `assemble` and `cheerio`). Thus when I `npm install lodash@3.10.1` it complains about unmet dependencies.

I've tried removing `node_modules` and `npm clear cache` and `rm -rf $HOME/.npm` in different orders and combinations with no change.

How do I get `lodash@3.10.1` to install at the top-level and the requested version of `lodash` in all the dependencies (and not have the dependencies use the top-level copy of `lodash` -- which I thought was the normal way for `npm` to work)?

Preferably a solution would not require updating all the dependencies to new versions (assuming that is even possible). That could be a solution, but that would require a lot more validation to make sure nothing broke.

Comment: Is there an `npm-shrinkwrap.json` file? That's used to lock down dependency versions -- if it's there, `npm install` will ignore the `package.json` file.

Comment: That has fixed it. And as it turns out, I was the one who added the shrinkwrap. Guess I chalk it up to Friday afternoon brain.

Comment: Thanks @furydevoid, that was it for me too, if you make that an answer I'll upvote it!